# Is the nullspace of a matrix's transpose equal to the nullspace of its RREF's transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a matrix $ A $ and its RREF $ B $. Are $ Null(A^\intercal) $ and $ Null(B^\intercal) $ equal?

How should I go about this problem?

Comment: What does RREF mean?

Comment: @Leo Presumably *row reduced echelon form*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Conceptually, the row reduced echelon form of a matrix $A$ must be in the form of $PA$ for some nonsingular matrix $P$. However, $A^Tx=0$ is not equivalent to $A^TP^Tx=0$.

For a concrete counterexample, consider $A=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&0}$. Its RREF is $B=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$. However,
$$
A^T\pmatrix{1\\ 0}=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1\\ 0}=0\ne\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}\pmatrix{1\\ 0}=B^T\pmatrix{1\\ 0}.
$$